# Remove padding from Chart Area of ASP.NET AJAX Control TK Area Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Area Chart in my web page made using the ASP.NETS AJAX Control Toolkit Area Chart Control. There seems to be a lot of white space/padding in between the actual chart and the black likes around the border of the chart area. Does anybody know how to remove or reduce the amount of white space/padding. See image below:

[image: ASP.NET AJAX Area Chart]

Comment: Do you mean white space at the left side of the chart?

Comment: Yes sorry I should have been more clear, I mean the white space to the left of the vertical axis and to the right of the right side of the chart. Each side of the chart basically...

Comment: I'm afraid AreaChart does not have this option. You can dive into [AreaChart.js](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AjaxControlToolkit/Scripts/AreaChart.js) `drawAreas` function and try to tweak it or  modify generated SVG manually.
Either way, you can post a new proposal (or pull request) to Ajax Control Toolkit project at [CodePlex](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).